# web + worker role cost

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles, azure-configuration

I have to run a web crawler in background using Azure.

According to what I understood I have to setup a worker role configured with the background task and I have to setup a web role to show the web site ASP.NET MVC.

A simple question: how does it work for the payment? Two different roles means two different instances? Or I can reuse the same instance hosting two different roles?

Answer (score 3):

Each Role you define must contain 1 or more instances.  Each instance is a VM and you will be billed currently .12/hr per CPU core (or fraction thereof for XS roles).

You can combine the web site with worker role capabilities very easily.  By default, you should see a WebRole.cs that implements a RoleEntryPoint.  That is your worker role entry point in a web role.  You can combine whatever logic you want in there for the background task.